# WordPress свое двухуровневое меню

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

Есть проблема:

Нестандартное меню.

Есть простые ссылки, а есть dropdown

```
<div class="navbar w-nav" data-animation="default" data-collapse="medium" data-duration="400">
        <div class="nav-container w-container">
          <nav class="nav-menu w-nav-menu" role="navigation">

          <a class="nl w-nav-link" href="/newdiz/">Главная</a>
          <a class="nl w-nav-link" href="/newdiz/news/">Новости</a>
                    <!-- dropdown -->
            <div class="dd w-dropdown" data-delay="0">
              <div class="nl w-dropdown-toggle">
                <div class="icon w-icon-dropdown-toggle"></div>
                <div class="dd-txt">О центре</div>
              </div>
              <nav class="dropdown-list w-dropdown-list">

              <a class="dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="/newdiz/timetable/">Расписание занятий</a>
              <a class="dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="/newdiz/busyness/">График занятости</a>
              <a class="dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="/newdiz/course-main/">Направления</a>
            </div>
            <!-- !dropdown -->


            <a class="nl w-nav-link" href="/newdiz/affiliates/">Филиалы</a>

                        <!-- dropdown -->
            <div class="dd w-dropdown" data-delay="0">
              <div class="competition nl w-dropdown-toggle">
                <div class="icon w-icon-dropdown-toggle"></div>
                <div class="dd-txt">Соревнования / Competitions</div>
              </div>
              <nav class="dropdown-list w-dropdown-list">
              <a class="dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="/newdiz/rank/">Рейтинги</a>
              <a class="dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="/newdiz/schedules-all/">График соревнований</a>
              <a class="dropdown-link w-dropdown-link" href="/newdiz/results/">Итоги</a>

                        <!-- !dropdown -->

            </div><a class="nl w-nav-link" href="/newdiz/gallerys/">Галерея</a>
            <a class="nl w-nav-link" href="/newdiz/contacts/">Контакты</a>
            <a class="nl w-nav-link" href="/newdiz/testimonialsclients/">Отзывы</a></nav>
          <div class="menu-button w-nav-button" data-ix="scale">
            <div class="text-block-19">Меню</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Вывожу его через `<a></a>` без проблем

```
    <?php

if( $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('1') ) { // "Меню для шапки" - это название моего меню. Вы можете также использовать ID или ярлык
    $menu_list = '';
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        $title = $menu_item->title; // заголовок элемента меню (анкор ссылки)
        $idmen = $menu_item->ID; // id элемента меню 
        $url = $menu_item->url; // URL ссылки
        $parentyn = $menu_item->menu_item_parent; // внутренняя

        $menu_list .= '<a href="' . $url . '" class="nl w-nav-link">' . $title . ' '. $parentyn  .' </a>';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
}
        ?>
```

Но нужно совсем иное меню.

Вопрос - есть ли какая функция, чтобы узнать, есть ли у пункта меню дочерние подпункты?

Comment: смотрив сторону Jquery .each()

Comment: @IlyaYaremchuk а чем оно отличается от цикла пхп?

Comment: Игорь, ты напиши что тебе нужно, для чего именно тебе это нужно узнать и т д

Comment: "Вопрос - есть ли какая функция, чтобы узнать,- есть ли у пункта меню дочерние подпункты?" 
зачем мне "костыли" на Jquery, если может быть решение на PHP. поэтому и спросил - а какая разница между циклами на PHP и Jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Выводите меню не своим кодом, а через `wp_nav_menu()`. Сформированное меню будет иметь класс `menu-item-has-children` у тех элементов, которые содержат подменю.

Используемая вами функция `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` не возвращает никаких признаков наличия подменю у элемента, только у его дочерних элементов `menu_item_parent` не равен нулю.

Comment: $menu_item->menu_item_parent; приходится использовать. спасибо за ответ